# Turing Machine Vs Linear Bounded Automata

Tags: computational-complexity, automata, formal-languages

Example of language accepted by **Turing Machine** but not by **Linear Bounded Automata** ?
Is there any EXPSPACE language?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the language of pairs $(n,T)$ where $n$ is an integer and $T$ is a description of a Turing machine that, when started on an empty tape, eventually moves farther than $2^n$ squares away from the origin.

The empty language is in EXPSPACE. Wikipedia's [EXPSPACE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPSPACE) article mentions a known EXPSPACE-complete problem.

See also the [space hierarchy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem) which gives a simple diagonal construction of languages tailored to have specific space complexities.

Comment: Henning: Are the two parts of the question independent? Or, in part (2), does the OP want an example of a language accepted by a TM and not by a LBA, *with the additional restriction* that it is in EXPSPACE? I am unable to tell. (It seems to me you have implicitly assumed that it is the former; is that right?).

Comment: @Srivatsan: Good point. I didn't consider that the second question could be an additional restriction. It is not much of a restriction, though -- even my outrageous example here is in EXPSPACE, if $n$ is assumed to be input in unary.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize the space hierarchy theorem: it implies that exponential space is unnecessary for TM to be more powerful than a LBA, there are languages recognizable in $O(n \log n)$ space but not $O(n)$.